# How can I merge two lists of dicts in python with potentially different key-value pairs?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have two list of dicts, both of which are KVPs in different dicts.

```
oldItemsBought = [{
   "name" : <item name>,
   "quantity": <item quantity>,
   "billed": <item bill amount (qty * price)>
}
{
   "name" : <item name>,
   "quantity": <item quantity>,
   "billed": <item bill amount (qty * price)>
}.....]
newItemsBought = [{
   "name" : <item name>,
   "quantity": <item quantity>,
   "billed": <item bill amount (qty * price)>
}
{
   "name" : <item name>,
   "quantity": <item quantity>,
   "billed": <item bill amount (qty * price)>
}.....]
```

Here, the "name" keys can have same or different values in either list (old or new items respectively), but the quantities need to be merged (If keys are same, add quantities), and bill Amounts need to be added.

Is there an easier way of doing this append-or-update operation?

Comment: Just code it in the same way you would do it as a human. What do you do, step by step?

Comment: `"items":[...]` isn't even valid Python syntax, is it?

Comment: Yeah, it isn't valid. Isn't step by step iteration with loops going to be time consuming? (and too confusing eventually, since that was my first attempt)

Comment: Rule of thumb: make it work first, then optimize it if it's too slow. And the code seems to be slower than normal for-looping each bought lists actually.

Comment: Time consuming or not: if it works, that's better than the current solution. It will not be not confusing since everyone can understand your individual steps instead of having some confusing pythonic "all in one line" solution.

Comment: Seems your data structure isn't the easiest to work with considering how you wish to update the data. Perhaps you could instead use a dictionary with `name` as keys, and values being dictionaries with `quantity` and `billed` ? Then it would be trivial to do the update

Comment: @oskros That's something I've considered. It seems far harder to work with the list of dicts format.

Answer (score 1):

```
newList = []

is_dublicate = False

for item in newItemBought:
    for old_item in oldItemsBought:
        if item['name'] == old_item['name']:
            old_item['quantity'] += item['quantity']
            newList.append(old_item)
            oldItemsBought.remove(old_item)
            is_dublicate = True
            break

    if not is_dublicate:
        newList.append(item)

    is_dublicate = False


for item in oldItemsBought:
    newList.append(item)


print(newList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for olditem in oldItemsBought:
    for newitem in newItemsBought:
        if olditem["name"]==newitem["name"]:
            newitem["quantity"]+=olditem["quantity"]
            newitem["billed"]+=olditem["billed"]
            break
    else:
        print(olditem["name"],newitem["name"],olditem)
        newItemsBought.append(olditem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `groupby` to get all dictionaries sharing the same name:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

res = [{'name': k,
        'quantity': sum(item['quantity'] for item in g),
        'billed': sum(item['billed'] for item in g)}
       for k, g in groupby(oldItemsBought + newItemsBought, itemgetter('name'))]
```